# llenar arreglo en metodos

Tags: java

```
public class Borrar {
    static Persona persona[]=new Persona[3];
    static Persona p1=new Persona();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        crear_persona();
        persona=llenar_arreglo(p1);
        mostrar(persona);
        
    }
    
    public static void crear_persona(){
        persona[0]=new Persona("Paul",21,'m');
        persona[1]=new Persona("Ellie",14,'f');
        persona[2]=new Persona("Cue",17,'f');
    }
    
    public static Persona[] llenar_arreglo(Persona p){
        Persona per[]=new Persona[3];
        for (int i=0;i<per.length;i++){
            per[i]=p;
        }
        return per;
    }
    
    public static void mostrar(Persona p[]){
        for (int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
            System.out.println(p[i]);
            System.out.println(p[i].getNombre());
        }
    }
}
```

no se como mostrar los atributos de la clase persona por medio de arreglos en métodos instanciados, no se cual es el problema si en (llenar_arreglo) asigno el arreglo a la clase Persona, y luego lo retorno, para después mostrar cada atributo en (mostrar).

Comment: Si seguis tu codigo, vas a ver que el metodo llenar arreglo, no tiene ningun sentido, ya lo llenaste en CrearPersona, y luego tu metodo llenar_arreglo sobreescribe todo lo que hiciste y pone personas vacias.. saca esta linea: persona=llenar_arreglo(p1); y vas  a ver como todo funciona.

Comment: No repitas las preguntas por favor. En lugar de haber creado [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/548484/arreglos-en-metodos-de-una-clase),  lo correcto era [editar esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/548433/edit). Dado que recibiste respuesta, por favor, considera borrar esta pregunta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [arreglos en metodos de una clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/548484/arreglos-en-metodos-de-una-clase)