# arreglos en metodos de una clase

Tags: java

```
public class Borrar {
    static AplicarMetodos metodo=new AplicarMetodos();
    static Persona persona[]=new Persona[3];
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        metodo.crear_persona();
        metodo.llenar_arreglo(persona);
        metodo.mostrar_arreglo(persona);
    }
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------
public class AplicarMetodos {
    static Persona persona[]=new Persona[3];
    
    public void crear_persona(){
        persona[0]=new Persona("Paul",21,'m');
        persona[1]=new Persona("Ellie",14,'f');
        persona[2]=new Persona("Cue",17,'f');
    }
    
    public Persona[] llenar_arreglo(Persona p[]){
        for (int i=0;i<persona.length;i++){
            persona=p;
        }
        return persona;
    }
    
    public void mostrar_arreglo(Persona p2[]){
        for (int i=0;i<p2.length;i++){
            System.out.println(p2[i]);
           /* System.out.println("Nombre: "+p2[i].getNombre());
            System.out.println("Edad: "+p2[i].getEdad());
            System.out.println("Sexo: "+p2[i].getSexo());
            System.out.println("");*/
        }
    }
}
```

-Esto en la clase main así como esta funciona, ***pero en una clase a main no funciona***, he realizado una comprobación para ver si el array tiene contenido en el método (mostrar_arreglo) y resulta que no tiene nada es nulo, ahora porque no tiene el contenido del arreglo persona si lo he agregado y guardado en el método (llenar_arreglo).

Comment: y como seria entonces, porque lo que quiero es mostrar cada atributo del arreglo persona, pero dentro del arreglo no suleto al aire, suelto seria como esta en el metodo (crear_persona). 
quiero mostrar nombre, edad, etc.

Answer (score 1):

con el método `crearPersona()` vos no solo estas creando objetos de tipo Persona si no que también estas rellenando el array `Persona[]persona` por ende como te lo comento gbianchi en su [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/548433/llenar-arreglo-en-metodos) el método `llenar_arreglo()` queda en desuso.

por que en la clase `AplicarMetodos` si funciona?

Esto es debido a que estas declarando un static array,el cual puede ser modificado solo en la clase donde esta siendo declarado,por lo cual si declaras una instancia de la clase `AplicarMetodos` en la clase `borrar` y haces usos de los métodos en mención te devolverá un Null,por que a diferencia de los metodos `rellenar_arreglo()` y `mostrar_arreglo()` el metodo `crear_persona()` no recibe un array `Persona[]p` como parametro ,en resumen en la clase borrar estas pasando un array `Persona[]p` vacio por que el metodo `crear_persona()` ademas de crear objetos llena el array declarado solo en la clase `AplicarMetodos()`que lleven el mismo nombre (persona) no significa que sean iguales.

tu codigo Modificado

```
     public class Borrar {
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            AplicarMetodos metodo=new AplicarMetodos();
            Persona[]p=new Persona[3];
            metodo.crear_persona(p);
            metodo.mostrar_arreglo(p);
        }
    }
================================
        public class AplicarMetodos {
                
            public void crear_persona(Persona persona[]){
                persona[0]=new Persona("Paul",21,'m');
                persona[1]=new Persona("Ellie",14,'f');
                persona[2]=new Persona("Cue",17,'f');
            }
                
            public void mostrar_arreglo(Persona p2[]){
                for (int i=0;i<p2.length;i++){
                    System.out.println("Nombre: "+p2[i].getNombre());
                    System.out.println("Edad: "+p2[i].getEdad());
                    System.out.println("Sexo: "+p2[i].getSexo());
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                
              AplicarMetodos metodo=new AplicarMetodos();
              Persona []p=new Persona[3];
              metodo.crear_persona(p);
              metodo.mostrar_arreglo(p);
        
            }
        }
```